# Issue on Adding Horizontal Line Before and After Paragraph

Tags: css

Can you please let me knoe how I can upgrade the following code to make the result looks like

[image]

```css
p::before {
   content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #f00;
}
p::after {
   content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12"><p>paragraph text</p></div>
```

Right now I am getting this

[image]

Comment: Probably change the `display` to `inline-block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed `display` to `inline-block` and I also changed margin to a `em` value so it will scale according to font-size

```css
p::before {
   content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0.3em;
    background: #f00;
}
p::after {
   content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0.3em;
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12"><p>paragraph text</p></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Omix22 fixed now